# Hangman append progress not working properly

Tags: java, append, character-arrays

My applyGuess method returns the user's progress after each guess, if his guess, in this case is a letter, is inside I append it (+=) to progress, and all the letters soon to be guessed are represented and printed on screen with '*' (stars). For example, the user guessed *'a'* and the word has two a's; **a***a*** (The output) and, for second guess lets choose the letter *'n'* if the user guesses *'n'*, we get; *n**** and not

> an**a*

```
  public String applyGuess(char letterGuessed){
    boolean isLetterInside = hiddenWord.indexOf(letterGuessed) >= 0; 
    char display;
    String progress;

    if (isLetterInside){
        for (char letter: hiddenWord.toCharArray()){
            display = '*';
            if (letter == letterGuessed){
                display = letterGuessed;
                }
            progress += display;
            }
    } else {
        misses++;
        }
    return progress;
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You need someway to maintain what the user has already guessed previously

Comment: Would putting his guess in a private member variable and returning that, do the job? thx

Comment: Where you are keeping record of previously guessed characters?

Comment: @niyasc  I'm not keeping any record, should I stored all the hits in a variable?

Comment: Another thing, may be a typo mistake. You are declaring boolean variable as `isLetterInside` and later it is refered as `letterInside`

Comment: @user2426691, Yeah, otherwise how will you know about previously guessed characters.

Comment: @niyasc lol don't worry about that, it's a typo mistake I just did while posting not in my code ;) Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might be able to do, is keep track of all the guesses that the user has made and build a new prompt on each successive guess.

```
private String hiddenWord = "banana";
private Set<Character> guesses = new HashSet<>();
private int misses;


public String applyGuess(char letterGuessed) {
    if (!guesses.contains(letterGuessed)) {
        guesses.add(letterGuessed);
        if (!hiddenWord.contains(Character.toString(letterGuessed))) {
            misses++;
        }
    }
    char[] progress = hiddenWord.toCharArray();
    for (int index = 0; index < hiddenWord.length(); index++) {
        if (!guesses.contains(hiddenWord.charAt(index))) {
            progress[index] = '*';
        }
    }
    return new String(progress);
}
```

What this basically does is checks to see if the user has already used this character or not (I did this so I wouldn't increment the `misses` count, but you're requirements might be different), adds the `char` to the list of guesses and then checks to see if the character is in the `hiddenWord`, if it isn't it increments the `misses`.

Because, regardless of what the user does, we need to produce a prompt, the last part of the method creates a `char` of the `hiddenWord` and loops over each character in the `hiddenWord`, where there isn't a matching guess in `guesses`, it updates the character at that position with a `*` character.

It then returns a `String` representation of the `char` array.

Doing something like...

```
System.out.println(applyGuess('n'));
System.out.println(applyGuess('a'));
System.out.println(applyGuess('b'));
```

Outputs

```
**n*n*
*anana
banana
```

for example

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the output only displays a letter instead of an * if the `letter` is equal to `letterGuessed`.  in your second example you pass an "n" in which is not equal to "a" so it made it a * overwriting the old string.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in several ways. One possible solution is:

```
Set<Character> previousGuesses = new HashSet<Character>();

public String applyGuess(char letterGuessed){
    boolean isLetterInside = hiddenWord.indexOf(letterGuessed) >= 0; 
    char display;
    String progress;

    if (isLetterInside){
    previousGuesses.add(letterGuessed);
        for (char letter: hiddenWord.toCharArray()){
            display = '*';
            if (previousGuessess.contains(letter)){
                display = letter;
                }
            progress += display;
            }
    } else {
        misses++;
        }
    return progress;
}
```